# How to get name attribute of a react-select using event.target.name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const Home = () => {

    const animals = [
        { label: 'cat', value: 'cat' },
        { label: 'dog', value: 'dog' },
        { label: 'lion', value: 'lion' },
        { label: 'eagle', value: 'eagle' },
    ]
}

return (

<>
 
 <Select 
         name="animals" 
         options={animals} 
         strong text**isMulti 
         onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.name)} 
  />

</>

)
```

**in console when i select some item it will give me this error

cannot read property of undefined (reading 'name')
at onChange

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it will **return an array of object(s) `{label: '', value: ''}` rather than an `event` object**.

```
 <Select 
    name="animals" 
    options={animals} 
    isMulti 
    onChange={(value, actionMeta) => console.log(actionMeta.name)} 
 />
```

Comment: yes sir but i want to get the name sir not the value

Comment: Still not clear. Are you trying the get the list of selected options? Can you mention that in the question? @mailtester

Comment: <Select name="this value i want to get sir"  /> 
<option value="not this value">item</option>